# Adding one year to a date field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, dateadd

I have a table in postgresql with a field_date using the syntax 'YYYY-MM-DD', I want to add a year to the field with the the sentence:

**UPDATE table SET date_field = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, date_field);**

but postgres return:

**ERROR:  column "year" does not exist**

I can't see what's wrong with the sentence

Comment: Try `set datefield = datefield + interval '1 year'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine

Comment: Please make sure that you mark Tim's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET date_field = date_field + interval '1 year'
```

It appears that you were trying to use SQL Server's `DATEADD()` function, which does not exist in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

select CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 year'

In your case you trying to do it in Transact SQL not in Postgres.

Try to use:
DATEADD->  "DATE + interval '1 year'"